# How to stop nested setTimeout call after a fixed time?

Tags: javascript, function, settimeout, nested-function

I have this piece of code:

```
let timerId = setTimeout(function tick() {
   alert("tick");
   setTimeout(tick(), 1000);
 }, 1000);
```

This creates an infinite loop that doesn't end. How can I stop this setTimeout after suppose 10000 ms or 10 s?

Comment: Use setInterval instead, then a setTimeout for the 10 seconds. When the latter expires, use clearInterval.

Comment: @ChrisG I know that method, but I strictly want to use nested setTimeout

Comment: In that case use a counter. You only want 10 iterations, so increase by one each time and if counter === 10, don't call setTimeout again.

Comment: Why exactly do you *want* to use a nested setTimeout? Is this some sort of silly homework/interview problem that's forcing you to operate with odd constraints?

Answer (score 0):

A soluation is to push the `timeout` to array when everytime you create it and loop over the array to clear it.

```
    let arr = []
    let timerId = setTimeout(function tick() {
       console.log("tick");
       arr.push(setTimeout(tick(), 1000));
     }, 1000);


    setTimeout(function(){
    arr.forEach(i=>{
     window.clearTimeout(i)
     }))
     },10000)
```

But, it always stable to use `setInterval()`:

```js
let arr = []
setInterval(function tick() {
   console.log("tick");
 }, 1000);
```